# sorting json by value and then extract the first value

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I receive such a response body from `HTTP` action in logic app:

```
[
  {
    "refreshId": "08702296-a2ad-43c5-8729-71dc7af27361",
    "startTime": "2019-02-28T14:53:34.9",
    "endTime": "2019-02-28T15:03:52.62",
    "status": "failed"
  },
  {
    "refreshId": "30484b8a-1934-4ffa-9377-ac9e558614fe",
    "startTime": "2019-02-08T20:20:51.2",
    "endTime": "2019-02-08T20:20:51.9",
    "status": "failed"
  },
  {
    "refreshId": "34b23346-9b6c-4d94-bf77-adc129babaa1",
    "startTime": "2019-02-17T05:37:48.067",
    "endTime": "2019-02-18T07:11:44.167",
    "status": "failed"
  },
  {
    "refreshId": "4a9b715c-e4df-4beb-b1f4-ef696e0c23bb",
    "startTime": "2019-03-05T16:05:22.97",
    "endTime": "2019-03-05T16:28:15.01",
    "status": "failed"
  }

]
```

I would like to sort this body on `starttime` and then extract the `refreshId`of the first one. Can I do it in Logic app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *Select* action to output all of the `startTime` values as an array of `ticks`:

[image]

[image]

Then use a *Filter* action to find the record with the min or max (depending on what you meant by "first one") tick value:

[image]
[image]

From there, you can use `body('Filter_array')[0].refreshId` to extract the data that you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: In _SELECT_ action I get the following error: The from property value in the select  of type "Object". The Value must be array.  does it possible to convert my Json to array?

Comment: Sure, you can wrap the Select.input.from value in the array() function. I'm curious, though, what is the current value of the data that you're inputting to the _Select_ action? Is this a scenario where the HTTP trigger is sending you only one object?

Comment: The output which I use in _SELECT_ is look like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neWtCKJNabDM5lCP3Eb7CPB4oag-vqb7/view?usp=sharing) I have tried something like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EgvPCa9cYZFWZAvosJHtI5wx98Qo8dnm/view?usp=sharing), but doesnt work

Comment: You have a small syntax issue. Try this: `"from": "@array(body('Get_All_refresh_Ids'))"`. If this http request is your trigger than you can replace `body('Get_All_refresh_Ids')` with `triggerBody()`.

Comment: I think I should also change `@ticks(item().StartTime)`, because I get with this statement **invalid template**. I have also test `@ticks(triggerBody().StartTime)` and `@ticks(triggerBody()?['StartTime']` but doesnt work. Do you have any idea how should I change it?

Comment: Your syntax for the `"select"` property looks correct. If you dump your template somewhere I'll take a look.

Comment: After reading your post, your post also works for me. Thanks y lot. Only one point: Where should I put `body('Filter_array')[0].refreshId` to get refreshid? Sorry I am really new in Logic Apps

Comment: My _Outputs_ that you see above were from a _Compose_ action but it really depends on what you ultimately plan to do with this refreshId. If you just want to see the value in a workflow run then a _Compose_ should be fine.